# Centering text inside a sibling image

Tags: css

Trying to center sibling div in the middle of the other sibling.

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-first">        
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">
    <span class="field-content"><a href="https://example.com/"target="_blank">Example Name</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-project-image">
    <div class="field-content"><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">
      <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://example.com/img.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

So Example Name would appear in the very dead center of the image.

It should look like this:

```
------------------------
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|     Example Name     |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
------------------------
```

EDIT: Stuff I've tried, which will be of absolutely no value to anyone in answering this question, but which is apparently required for it:

I've tried this:

```
.views-field-title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

I've tried this:

```
.views-field-title {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50em;
position: absolute;
```

}

And this:

```
.views-field-title {
    text-align: center;
    top: 25em;
    width: 100%;
}

.views-field-title a {
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific, also is there a CSS with this ?

Comment: More specific how? I want Example Name to be right in the middle of the image. Like dead center. And I'm not sure how CSS would be relevant, I'll just modify any examples given here to suit my condition. I currently don't have it centered at all.

Comment: so in other world you want the text to be centred over the image ?

Comment: I'll include a text graphic to show what I want

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. SO is not a markup writing service.

Comment: Everything I've tried is stupid because I'm not sure how to do this specifically, and nothing I've tried will be of absolutely any value in answering the question, but sure I'll post the garbage I've tried.

Comment: The purpose in you showing your markup is to make sure we're following along correctly. We can also see what garbage you've written and how stupid you are so we can then educate you into a smart developer so you won't have to ask as many stupid questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure about the CSS you have in your page, but you can try using some positionning in order to make the text above the image and flex to center the text inside :

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.views-row {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.views-field-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.views-field-title:after,.views-field-title:before {
 content:"";
 flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-first">
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">
    <span class="field-content"><a href="https://example.com/"target="_blank">Example Name</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-project-image">
    <div class="field-content">
      <a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">
        <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This appears to work. Can you post a link to exactly what you did? I'm guessing this is related to flexbox?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander yes sure. I have done two main things 1) i used absolute position to make the element above the image and cover all the area (that's why all values at 0) 2) i used flex for centering the element inside the container. You can read more about flex :https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @AndrewAlexander i also used two other CSS rules like making the image to not overflow the container. And i made the whole container to be inline-block to only be stretched to it's content and not getting full with (you may add border and remove this property and you will understand)

Answer (score 1):

You need to absolutely position the title inside of the main container.

Horizontal centering is easy.

Vertical centering is a little tricky.  Can you change the HTML?  If so, you can add a span tag and use it as a "vertical helper" to force the vertical centering.

Here's the CSS:

```
.views-row-first {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.views-field-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.views-field-title .field-content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.views-field-title .vertical-helper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-first">        
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">
    <span class="field-content">
      <a href="https://example.com/"target="_blank">Example Name</a>
    </span>
    <span class="vertical-helper"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-project-image">
    <div class="field-content"><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">
      <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Natural-Dog-Law-2-To-dogs%2C-energy-is-everything.jpg?itok=Z-ujUOUr"></a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

And here's a working demo on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/979dnd36/

Comment: no need to add extra element, you may do it with :after to avoid changing the structure (if you are not allowed of course) ;)

Comment: i also suggest to use snippet to add working code directly in the site ... as it's better to see the result here, jsfiddle links may dead one day

Comment: Yeah, I can get the horizontal centering pretty easily but the vertical is the trouble. And I have full control over the HTML/CSS etc. I'm just way more backend than frontend. Especially when it comes to absolute positioning.

Comment: yes, but i was giving a small hint to avoid touching the HTML. have a look at this and you will understand ;) https://jsfiddle.net/979dnd36/1/

Comment: @AndrewAlexander the only HTML I added was this:
<span class="vertical-helper"></span>

Other than that, you can copy/paste the CSS.  I think the one thing you were missing was to make the main div/container position:relative.  When you absolutely position something, you have to tell it where you want it to be contained.

Comment: I remember reading about that at one point vaguely. I'll look into it, though I ultimately went with the flexbox solution someone else posted. The biggest problem with frontend development is that it seems to be based on memorization of a lot of idiosyncratic rules.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Yeah, CSS is certainly not logical most of the time.